# How to load a zip file with pyscript and save into the virtual file system

Tags: python, python-zipfile, pyscript, virtualfilesystem

I am trying to load a zip file and save it in the virtual file system for further processing with pyscript. In this example, I aim to open it and list its content.

As far as I got:

See the self standing html code below, adapted from [tutorials](https://www.jhanley.com/pyscript-files-and-file-systems-part-1/) (with thanks to the author, btw)

It is able to load Pyscript, lets the user select a file and loads it (although not in the right format it seems). It creates a dummy zip file and saves it to the virtual file, and list the content. All this works upfront and also if I point the process_file function to that dummy zip file, it indeed opens and lists it.

The part that is NOT working is when I select via the button/file selector any valid zip file in the local file system, when loading the data into `data` it is text (utf-8) and I get this error:

```
File "/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py", line 1353, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("Bad magic number for central directory")
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad magic number for central directory
```

I have tried saving to a file and loading it, instead of using BytesIO , also tried variations of using ArrayBuffer or Stream from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)
I have also tried creating a FileReader and using readAsBinaryString() or readAsText() and various transformations, with same result: either it fails to recognise the "magic number" or I get "not a zip file".
When feeding some streams or arrayBuffer I get variations of:

```
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'pyodide.JsProxy'
```

At this point I suspect there is something embarrassingly obvious that yet I am unable to see, so, any fresh pair of eyes and advice on how best/simply load a file is much appreciated :)
Many thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Example</p>
    <br />
    <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="print_output"></div>
    <br />
    <p>File Content:</p>
    <div style="border:2px inset #AAA;cursor:text;height:120px;overflow:auto;width:600px; resize:both">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>

    <py-script output="print_output">
        import asyncio
        import zipfile
        from js import document, FileReader
        from pyodide import create_proxy
        import io

        async def process_file(event):
            fileList = event.target.files.to_py()
            for f in fileList:
                data= await f.text()
                mf=io.BytesIO(bytes(data,'utf-8'))

            with zipfile.ZipFile(mf,"r") as zf:
                nl=zf.namelist()
                nlf=" _ ".join(nl)
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=nlf

        def main():
            # Create a Python proxy for the callback function
            # process_file() is your function to process events from FileReader
            file_event = create_proxy(process_file)
            # Set the listener to the callback
            e = document.getElementById("myfile")
            e.addEventListener("change", file_event, False)

            mf = io.BytesIO()
            with zipfile.ZipFile(mf, mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
                zf.writestr('file1.txt', b"hi")
                zf.writestr('file2.txt', str.encode("hi"))
                zf.writestr('file3.txt', str.encode("hi",'utf-8'))  
            with open("a.txt.zip", "wb") as f: # use `wb` mode
                f.write(mf.getvalue())
            
            with zipfile.ZipFile("a.txt.zip", "r") as zf:
                nl=zf.namelist()
                nlf=" ".join(nl)

            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = nlf


        main()
    </py-script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close with your code. The problem was in converting the file data to the correct data type. The requirement is to convert the `arrayBuffer` to `Uint8Array` and then to a `bytearray`.

Import the required function:

```
from js import Uint8Array
```

Read the file `data` into an `arrayBuffer` and copy it to a new `Uint8Array`

```
data = Uint8Array.new(await f.arrayBuffer())
```

Convert the `Uint8Array` to a `bytearray` that BytesIO expects

```
mf = io.BytesIO(bytearray(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

For reference, based on John Hanley's response (thanks again!), here is the working code, adding a demonstration of saving as binary in the virtual file systems and loading it from that file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <title>File Example</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Example</p>
    <br />
    <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="print_output"></div>
    <br />
    <p>File Content:</p>
    <div style="border:2px inset #AAA;cursor:text;height:120px;overflow:auto;width:600px; resize:both">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>

    <py-script output="print_output">
        import asyncio
        import zipfile
        from js import document, FileReader, Uint8Array
        from pyodide import create_proxy
        import io

        async def process_file(event):
            fileList = event.target.files.to_py()
            for f in fileList:
                data = Uint8Array.new(await f.arrayBuffer())
                mf = io.BytesIO(bytearray(data))
                with zipfile.ZipFile(mf,"r") as zf:
                    nl=zf.namelist()
                    nlf=" ".join(nl)
                    document.getElementById("content").innerText+= "\n Test 2: reading file from local file system: "+f.name+" content:"+nlf
                with open("b.zip","wb") as outb:
                    outb.write(bytearray(data))
                with zipfile.ZipFile("b.zip", "r") as zf:
                    nl=zf.namelist()
                    nlf=" ".join(nl)
                document.getElementById("content").innerText += "\n Test 3: reading the same file but first save it in virtual fs and read it: " + nlf
    
    

        def main():
            # Create a Python proxy for the callback function
            # process_file() is your function to process events from FileReader
            file_event = create_proxy(process_file)
            # Set the listener to the callback
            e = document.getElementById("myfile")
            e.addEventListener("change", file_event, False)

            mf = io.BytesIO()
            with zipfile.ZipFile(mf, mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
                zf.writestr('file1.txt', b"hi")
                zf.writestr('file2.txt', str.encode("hi"))
                zf.writestr('file3.txt', str.encode("hi",'utf-8'))  
            with open("a.zip", "wb") as f: # use `wb` mode
                f.write(mf.getvalue())
            
            with zipfile.ZipFile("a.zip", "r") as zf:
                nl=zf.namelist()
                nlf=" ".join(nl)

            document.getElementById("content").innerText = "Test 1: reading a dummy zip from virtual file system: " + nlf


        main()
    </py-script>

</body>

</html>
```